# How to change the text of color in drawRect Method

Tags: ios, drawrect

I want to change the color of the text in `drawRect:` method when clicking on a color buttons in my `switchColor` method.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect withColor:(UIColor*) color
```

{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

```
CGColorRef red = color.CGColor;
NSLog (@"color is %@",red);
//CGColorRef color = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:3.0 blue:2.0 alpha:1.0]);

CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(130,200,120,120));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,red);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(130, 200, 120, 120));
```

}

error CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0... please help me

Comment: Show us some code of what have you tried so far

Comment: Im trying add the buttons to the view using the switchColor: method..please help me

Answer (score 0):

use

**CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, textColor);**

Comment: instead of giving the textcolor directky i want to call the method with different button colors

Comment: The way to do it without CG is

[[UIColor redColor] set];

or whatever colour you want.

Comment: CGColorRef red = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(130,200,120,120));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,red); is this the way to get the color